# How to update all records of a table by replacing values of a column by ids found in another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

The sqlite3 table 'myTable' contains a record like this:

```
id:2, word:'french', language:'#french'
```

and a record with:

```
id:5555, word:'bonjour', language:'#french'
```

The idea is to replace all the language fields with the corresponding id and get:

```
id:5555, word:'bonjour', language:'2'
```

(word being unique)

The following query fails to do so. I must be missing something very obvious (sorry if I am). Can anyone help correct this or find a simpler query?

```
UPDATE myTable as t1 
    SET t1.language = (
        SELECT t2.id FROM myTable t2 
            WHERE substr(t1.language,2) = t2.word
    ) WHERE t1.language like '#%';
```

I tried the following to no avail:

```
UPDATE myTable 
    SET t1.language = t2.id 
        from myTable as t1 inner join myTable as t2
        on substr(t1.language,2) = t2.word
    WHERE t1.language like '#%';
```

-- From what I read and after numerous tests, it looks like "UPDATE myTable as t1" doesn't work in sqlite3. I would be very grateful if someone had a suggestion.

Comment: This is a bad design. Create a separate table for languages and then store the ids in the current table.

Comment: Could those with a smug tone and no idea of the answer leave space for a real SQL query suggestion? (Thanks). Jugements on the data structure will not help. That's how the table is.

Comment: If you find a suggestion about your design *smug* (I had to google it) then you are at the wrong site.

Comment: As I explained, this it is not my design. The data is like this. I am looking for an SQL query. Believing the interlocutor is dumb by default is not the best approach. I am sorry but you were stating the obvious in your remark. This was a question about SQL.

Comment: *As I explained, ...* where and when?

Answer (score 0):

One simple query is

```
update myTable
set language = (select id from myTable t2
where t2.language = myTable.language
and t2.word = substr(myTable.language,2))
where word != substr(language,2)
and language like '#%'
```

Note that this will not update the "language" row(s) (id 2 in the sample data) by the `where word != substr(language,2)` filter ; once that row is updated no other rows would update.

Since this is a "destructive" SQL, written with limited knowledge of the full scope of the data, backup, backup, backup!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I don't know if it is a problem with aliases in sqlite3 but it is driving me nuts. I have solved it in a very ugly way by duplicating the table but it will not work in production. As for your query, in my example above, it replaces all language fields with '2' whatever #word they contain (#spanish, #English...). This is actually what I obtained in my previous attempts. (Only working with backups, of course. Thanks.)